# Connecting REST API to Tableau

Tags: postman, tableau-api, rest

I am trying to use REST API to connect data into Tableau Desktop. Which option do I select when choosing the datasource when opening Tableau Desktop? I have tested the API in Postman, and it successfully connects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API is not a data source that can be accessed from Tableau Desktop. To use the REST API you have to export the data from an API call to csv or other flat file. Then you can connect Tableau Desktop to that file. You can automate this using Python. You can also export directly from Postman. At the top of your results after you run your GET, download the file from here [image: here]

I do strongly recommend you do this all in Python rather than Postman though so you can consume the json file much more easily with `pandas`. I would also recommend looking at `tableauserverclient` within Python rather than using the API directly. `tableauserverclient` is more limited than the API but will likely have the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau cannot connect to REST API directly.

One way is to use Web Data Connector, BUT you have to build a web page for each REST API and paste the web page link in Web Data Connector.

Alternatively, you can use ETL tools that support extracting data from API and loading it to Tableau. (I personally recommend Acho. Its API connector is very useful)